# How do I make a PDA own a system account

Tags: anchor, account

So im making a program that CPIs into marinade. In one of the instructions, they have a "transfer_sol_to" account requirement. I want the sol from that instruction to be transferred to a programs vault. I know if they simply mutated the value of the sol balance of the account this would be possible however looking at their code they use the system_instruction::transfer function to transfer to the "transfer_sol_to" account. So the question is, how do I make a system account that is owned by a PDA?

Anchor btw

Comment: What do you mean by a system account? Also(and do correct me on this), I assume that your actual aim here is to transfer sol to a PDA vault?

Comment: yes i just want to transfer sol to a PDA vault. The marinade instruction im calling will use the system_instruction::transfer to transfer the sol to the account i pass in as `transfer_sol_to`

Answer (score 3):

Before it's created, your PDA is a system program account. So instead of `init`ing the PDA just send solana to it. And then sign using its seeds whenever you want to `transfer` sol out of it using the system program instructions.

So don't make a PDA that owns a system program account, just use a PDA that *is* a system program account.

Comment: Just make sure that the PDA account is always rent exempt (`rent.minimum_balance(0)`).  If it ever goes below that value then the blockchain will deduct rent for each epoch.

Comment: how do i make it rent exempt without  initing?

Comment: Just put sol in it