# How can I verify if a PDA exists in solana program (using Rust)?

Tags: pda

I am new to solana. How can I verify if a PDA exists inside a solana Rust program. I checked online docs and google for blogs. I did not find the answer.

So what I am trying to is a user call one of my program instruction. I will use this user's public key and the program Id to find a pda. And then check if this pda exists. If it does not, I will create a PDA for this user as the user profile. So how can I check the existence of the PDA?

Thank you!

Thanks for the replying. Let me give more info. First, I am not using Anchor. It is solana plain rust program. And what I want to do is as follows:

```
pub fn do_something(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
other: String
) -> ProgramResult {
let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let profile_pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

// validation
let (profile_pda, bump_seed) =
    Pubkey::find_program_address(&[initializer.key.as_ref()], program_id);
if profile_pda != *profile_pda_account.key {
    msg!(
        "Invalid seeds for PDA. input={}, calulated={}",
        profile_pda_account.key,
        profile_pda
    );
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
}

// check existense
if //profile_pda_account not exist {
    //create the pda
}
// do something
//...
}
```

Comment: Is this in Anchor or plain Solana? Also do you have to check? Do you have something against trying to create the PDA anyways and trusting that it'll fail if it already exists?

Comment: Thanks @Ademola. It is plain Solana. Please see my above code. I do not just want to error our if it exist. I need to do something else based on the content of this pda if it exists

Comment: Got it. I'm adding an answer now

Answer (score 3):

**check inside program**

Add `#[account(init_if_needed)]` constraint to your account (in Anchor) this will initialize the PDA only if it's not already initialized.

**check off-chain**

First, you need to get the PDA `address`, you'll have to use something like `PublicKey.findProgramAddress` [source](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#findProgramAddress). then get the `account info` of the PDA which will return  [- if the requested account doesn't exist](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getaccountinfo).

Keep in mind that all accounts in Solana are [System Accounts](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/how-do-i-make-a-pda-own-a-system-account) by default. Even if it's never been initialized. So unless you are working with token accounts or data accounts. You don't have to check.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not using Anchor. I updated my question, adding more info. Could you please take another look? Thank you!

Comment: it follows the same **off-chain** check principle but it's easier since you have access to account info of any account that is passed to your program implicitly. You can check if the data exists if so it's initialized.

Comment: Hi @vicyyn, how to check if the data exists in rust? I am also not very familiar with rust. LOL

Comment: in your `accounts`, your accounts Infos have values like rent epoch and data https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.5.0/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html

You can simply view if there's data allocated, also you can check if the rent epoch is a valid number, it should be something like 0 or a weird number~ if it's not rent exempt.

Answer (score 1):

The code in our instruction that checks if an account is already initialized is something like:

```
if **profile_pda_account.try_borrow_lamports()? > 0 {
       msg!("This account has been initialized");
       initialized = true;
} else {
       msg!("Account is not initialized");
       initialized = false;
}
```

Uninitialized accounts have 0 lamports.

Comment: Do you mean if the pda exists, then the lamports must > 0? Is it possible that the lamports were consumed to 0 by this pda, or it guarantees the pda's lamports cannot be used except it is deleted?

Comment: An account can have >0 lamports and still be non initialized, any System Account can receive sol.

Comment: @ZhihengXie Yes. An account is closed as soon as its balance runs down to 0 lamports(validators delete it to save disk space as it's not paid for anymore).

Comment: @vicyyn Sending sol to a non-initialized account is how it is initialized.

Comment: Is it possible to initialize an account that has sol? e.g. System Account

Comment: Doubtful. The standard(maybe even only) way to close an account is to zero its lamport balance. Any account that has sol is by default already initialized.

Comment: My understanding is that account existence = initialized = created, there is no existing account that is not initialized. Is my saying correct?

Comment: If by "existence" we mean "tracked by validators" then yes. Transactions can only be done on accounts that validators track so yh an account needs to have been initialized/created before it exists on a block.